# Angular Material available only when imported via Shared Module in Router Module

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-routing, angular-module

Following the Angular guidelines, I am trying to create a sample project which consists of several feature modules.

In order to use Angular Material in each of the modules, I have created a shared module which imports and exports these material modules. This Shared Module is imported wherever Angular Material is required.

According to the guidelines, each of the feature module should have it's own Router Module and thus I have created one for each feature.

I want to keep just the routing related items in the Routing Module thus imported the Shared Module in the Feature Module and to my surprise it did not work i.e. Material directives were not working.

```
//Feature Module
@NgModule({
    imports: [..., SharedModule], //SharedModule import doesn't make material available
    declarations: []
})
```

Once I imported this Shared Module in Router Module, the Material components started to work.

```
//Feature Router Module
@NgModule({
    imports: [..., SharedModule], //SharedModule makes material available
    declarations: []
})
```

How can I make it work by importing the Shared Module in the Feature Module?

Demo at: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-segregated-modules?embed=1&file=src/app/Modules/Sub/sub.module.ts

Comment: FYI: This *recommended approach* hasn't worked well for me over the years. I stopped using share module to import Material modules. What I found is that it becomes impossible to tell what modules are used or not. So you might as well just import EVERYTHING because in a couple of months that's basically what's going to happen. So I prefer to create small shared modules that only import the Material modules they need directly. The one component per module approach works very well for me.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Reactgular

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the StackBlitz you linked, `SubComponent` is declared in `SubRoutesModule`. The component will only have access to the imports of the module it's declared in, which explains the problem you describe.

> How can I make it work by importing the Shared Module in the Feature Module?

Remove `SubComponent` from the declarations in `SubRoutesModule` and add it to the declarations in `SubModule`.

Comment: Thanks! But I would anyways have to import the `SubComponent` again in the route module to include it in the routes? I hope just by importing and not including the component in the declarations array is not a overhead for angular to. Just want to confirm again though I am sure.

Comment: Yup that is correct. You need to import the `SubComponent` at the top of the file so that you can create a route with it, but it should not be included in the declarations in router modules `@NgModule` metadata